# How to check file size and then echo?

Tags: command-line, files

Currently I'm trying to check file size from reading a directory

```
read directory

dirsize=$(du -sh $directory)

if [[ "$dirsize" -ge 2MB ]]; then
  echo 'High'

elif [[ "$dirsize" -le 2MB ]]; then
  echo 'Low'

fi
```

The problem is when I check file size, the output will be like

4.0K ./......./...
32M  ./......./...

So, when I write my code it doesn't work and I don't know how to fix.
For example,

```
if [[ "$dirsize" -ge 2MB ]]; then
   echo 'High'
```

From code above, my point is to echo 'High' if file is greater than 2MB.
Could you give advice please.

Comment: Your trying to compare strings with -ge and -le. String compares can only be == (equal) or != (not equal).

Comment: Use "du -bs" to get total bytes. And compare sizes.

Comment: Does [this help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/548755/495805)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`du` returns the size and the file/directory name. As you only need the size you just read the first part. And you need the bytes, not the iec size.

You can use `numfmt` to convert iec numbers to bytes (see `man numfmt`).

Numbers can be compared by bash with number compare operators (see `man test`).

```
# use only the first part of the output from "du" and use size in bytes
read -r size _ <<<"$( du -sb directory )"
# convert 2M to bytes
size2m="$( numfmt --from=iec 2M )"

# now compare the pure numbers
if [[ ${size} -ge ${size2m} ]]; then
    echo "High"
fi

if [[ ${size} -le ${size2m} ]]; then
    echo "Low"
fi
```

Comment: btw  for the first line read -r size _ <<<"$( du -sb directory )" what does "_ <<<" means??

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when I check file size, the output will be like
>
> 4.0K ./......./... 32M ./......./...

That output is the output you chose by providing the `-h` (`--human-readable`) option to `du`. You will have more success when you leave it out. Then, all sizes are printed in the same unit.